# Windows 7 - Apache crash

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have to code tiny and simple php script. I don't want to depend on remote servers, so I decided I will install my own environment. My workstation was Windows XP, installed Apache 2.2.11, php 5.2.9 and mysql - 5.1.22. Everything was ok, it worked as it was supposed to work...

Few days ago I upgraded to **windows 7**. Installed Apache 2.2.13 (keeping the old httpd.conf) and the same versions of php and mysql. Running scripts with the interpreter (using cmd) is ok, but when I try to reach them through the apache it crashes.

Here is my error log:

> [Mon Aug 17 15:05:14 2009] [notice]
> Parent: child process exited with
> status 255 -- Restarting.
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:14 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.13
> (Win32) PHP/5.2.9 configured --
> resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:14 2009] [notice] Server built:
> Aug  6 2009 15:50:50
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:14 2009] [notice] Parent:
> Created child process 6740
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:15 2009] [notice] Child 6740:
> Child process is running
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:15 2009] [notice] Child 6740:
> Acquired the start mutex.
>
> [Mon Aug 17
> 15:05:15 2009] [notice] Child 6740:
> Starting 64 worker threads.
>
> [Mon Aug
> 17 15:05:15 2009] [notice] Child 6740:
> Starting thread to listen on port 80.

Googling about "Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting." I found that this big is known on windows vista too, but I couldn't find a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my name is Angelo, and I'm a Web Master...
I Had this same problem, so i've tried anythings to figure out this problem.
Well, here, this problem was with 'libmysql.dll'
if you overwrite the '**libmysql.dll**' that comes with **PHP**, for the '**libmysql.dll**' comes with MySQL Database Server, that's it.
It's simple, recover the '**libmysql.dll**' that comes with PHP.
I discovered this problem, when i tried to access files with mysql commands.
so, that's it.
Bye, and apologize for my poor english!